# How do I get the datetime difference in calendar hours

Tags: mysql, date

How do I get the difference between two datetimes in calendar hours (to adjust for daylight savings time).

This was suggested on a SO post:  `time_to_sec(timediff(to_date, from_date))`.

But I get strange warnings:

```
select time_to_sec("65:00:00");
show warnings; -- nonthing

select time_to_sec("984:00:00");
show warnings; -- Truncated incorrect time value: '984:00:00
```

Do I just ignore these warnings?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [stated in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff), time_to_diff returns a TIME value and is limited to the range supported by the TIME field type: -838:59:59 -> 838:59:59. Your 984 hours is beyond the max supported value by ~150 hours.

Comment: So, is there another way to get the difference between two datetimes in hours?

Comment: use unix timestamps and some dvision, e.g. `(unix_timestamp(time1) - unix_timestamp(time2)) / (60*60)`. unix timestamps are just ints representing seconds since jan 1/70.